# Swift 3 Find position of the biggest Double in array

Tags: arrays, swift3, max, ios10

My Array:

```
let array = [45,12,10,90]
// The number I need in this case is 3
```

Then I need to grab a value of another array:

```
let otherArray = [6,6,7,4,0]
```

I have tried to resolve the problem like this:

```
let maxPosition = array.max()
let desiredValue = otherArray[maxPosition]
```

This doesn't seem to work as desired.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `array.max()` would return `90` which means you be effectively doing this `otherArray[90]` I hope you can see why this would give you an index out of bounds error :) *Hint: you need the index of 90*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem there is that max returns the maximum value from your array, not an index. You need to find the index of the maximum value and use it with your other array:

```
let array = [45,12,10,90]
let otherArray = [6,6,7,4,0]

if let maxValue = array.max(), let index = array.index(of: maxValue) {
    let desiredValue = otherArray[index]
    print(desiredValue)    // 4
}
```

Another option is to use your collection indices when getting the maximum value:

```
if let index = array.indices.max(by: { array[$0] < array[$1] }) {
    let desiredValue = otherArray[index]
    print(desiredValue)    // 4
}
```

Comment: This works, but it's 2 passes through the array. I think there was a version of `max` that returns both the index and the element, as a tuple. I can't find it now though D:

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
let array = [45,12,10,90]
let otherArray = [6,6,7,4,0]


var maxValueInArray = array[0]
for i in 1..<array.count{
    if array[i] > maxValueInArray{
        maxValueInArray = array[i]
    }
}

if let maxValueIndex = array.index(of: maxValueInArray){
    let desiredValueInOtherArray = otherArray[maxValueIndex]
    print("Maximum value in array is \(maxValueInArray) with index \(maxValueIndex). Value in otherArray under index \(maxValueIndex) is \(desiredValueInOtherArray)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the index of the highest value by comparing the elements in the array to its highest value:

```
let array = [45,12,10,90]
let otherArray = [6,6,7,4,0]

if let index = array.firstIndex(where: { $0 == array.max() }) {
   print(otherArray[index]) //4
}
```

Just be mindful that the two arrays are of different sizes, therefore the index of the highest value in one array could be out-of-bounds in the other array.